# cannot set cancel button to forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm learning on programming with C# windows forms. Then I discover `cancelButton` property. I try to set this property to my form so that when I hit ESC it would close my form. But when I double click `cancelButton` in my form's property, there nothing happen except VS marks my `Form1.cs` as unsaved. No method created after the double click. I tried to create `private void cancelButon(object sender, EventArgs e){}` but the dropdown box where I select method for `cancelButton` refuses to show my method. The same thing happens to `AcceptButton`. I have tried to create a brand new project, but it would not help.
Is that VS's bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the form's CancelButton and AcceptButton properties are for...

To make the form's `CancelButton` property work you first have to add a button to the form. Then you select that button from the drop-down list next to the form's `CancelButton` property.

What this does is to automatically click the Cancel button when the user presses the Escape key.

Similar logic applies to the form's `AcceptButton` property, except that it will cause the associated button to be clicked when the user presses the Enter key.

Having done that, you STILL HAVE TO ADD A HANDLER FOR THE BUTTON CLICKS.

To do that, double-click on the button in the form (displayed in the designer) - that is what will automatically add the handler for you.

To summarise:

> Form.CancelButton -> Determines which button will be clicked when user presses Escape.
>
> Form.AcceptButton -> Determines which button will be clicked when user 
>   presses Enter.
>
> To add a handler for a button, double click the button in the designer.

Comment: As I mention above, when I double click the property, nothing happen. No handler added, not thing happen at all. Even I create custom handler, there is nothing for me to choose in that property dropdown list

Comment: As Matthew mentioned, did you add buttons to your form? You first need to Add two buttons to your form, one for each action. Without those, you can't use the Cancel or Accept properties.

Comment: I did double click the button in the designer. But no thing added.
This is what I normally do: create the form, find cancelButton property, double click it to add handler, code that handler.
But just for the last hours, I cannot add handler for my those button. VS DO NOT let me do it.

Comment: you mean a real button? not only property?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use those properties without a real button on your form.

Comment: Do menu strip item/context menu strip item work too?

Comment: Again, afaik it is a button only property. 
You can search how to get keystrokes on your form and implement a method that, in case User press Esc do some thing, and if user press Enter do this other thing.